# Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer (Spring 5.2.3 + Spring Boot 2.2.3)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm using Spring `5.2.3.RELEASE` and Spring Boot `2.2.3.RELEASE`.

When trying to run some integration tests for my application, I'm getting the following error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer : org.springframework.boot.context.ConfigurationWarningsApplicationContextInitializer
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:445)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:427)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:420)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:272)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:253)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.acme.service.MyService.main(MyService.java:60)
    ... 8 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.KotlinDetector.isKotlinReflectPresent()Z
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:187)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:441)
```

I believe that this error relates to incompatible versions of some components.

This similar issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15970 says:

> isKotlinReflectPresent was added to Spring Framework in 5.1.
>   Therefore, I would suspect that you have some jars from Framework 5.0
>   (or earlier) in the classpath.

but I cannot determine which dependency is causing the problem?

Here is my pom.xml:

```
 <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.joschi.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-threetenbp</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.196</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
        <artifactId>logging-interceptor</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okio</groupId>
        <artifactId>okio</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.13</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.30</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.9</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-test-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
        <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.gsonfire</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson-fire</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And below is the result from `mvn dependency:tree`. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:tree (default-cli) @ my-service ---
[INFO] com.acmecorp.service:my-service:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.github.acmecorpapi:swagger-ui-annotation:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.webjars.npm:swagger-ui-dist:jar:3.20.6:runtime
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.2.3.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.2.3.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.2.3.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.12.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.12.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.25:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.2.3.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.10.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.10.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.10.2:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.2.3.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.30:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.30:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.2.3.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] |     \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.18.Final:runtime
[INFO] |        +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:runtime
[INFO] |        \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:runtime
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.6.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.acmecorp.logging:acmecorp-logging-logback:jar:1.0.0-36:runtime
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:runtime
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:runtime
[INFO] |  +- com.github.acmecorp.util:util-process-identifier:jar:1.16.0-118:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.2:runtime
[INFO] +- com.github.joschi.jackson:jackson-datatype-threetenbp:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:42.2.9:runtime
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.196:runtime
[INFO] +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.30:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:jar:9.0.30:compile
[INFO] +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.2.3.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.3.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.2.3.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.3.2:runtime
[INFO] |     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.11:runtime
[INFO] |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.2.3.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:3.4.2:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.2.3.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.2.3.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.threeten:threetenbp:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.flywaydb:flyway-core:jar:5.1.4:runtime
[INFO] +- com.acmecorp.service:my-service-contract:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:runtime
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.2.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.2.3.RELEASE:test
```

MyService.java

```
@AcmeCorpSwaggerUI("com.acme.service.my-service.contract") // Custom interface
@SpringBootApplication(
    scanBasePackages = {"io.swagger", "com.example.service"})
public class MyService implements WebMvcConfigurer
{

    @Value("${https.port}")
    private int httpsPort;

    @Value("${management.server.port}")
    private int adminPort;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(MyService.class, args);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: please post the result of mvn dependency:tree

Comment: Thanks @satyesht, added output of `mvn dependency:tree` to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This dependency, shown in `mvn dependency:tree` above, was bringing in an older version of Spring, resulting in the runtime error:

```
[INFO] +- com.github.acmecorpapi:swagger-ui-annotation:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE:compile
```

Options to resolve this are to:

- Update the above dependency to use Spring 5.2.3
- Use Spring 5.0.8 in my project

Answer (score 0):

You've since edited out your pom, but I suspect that it's due to you explicitly defining versions for dependencies that Spring Boot manages.

Your pom should have Spring Boot as its parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>demo</name>
  <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> <!-- No version defined -->
    </dependency>
...
```

I'd suggest grooming your pom by:

- Remove versions of dependencies that Spring Boot manages.
- Remove dependencies that are already brought in transitively by Spring Boot starters.

Comment: Thanks, I've added my pom.xml back in now if you'd like to take a look :-)